# How to use RabbitMQ and STOMP WebSockets in Javascript for making real-time chat operation?

Tags: javascript, websocket, rabbitmq, stomp

I have a web app with following tech stack

- HTML/CSS + JavaScript for front-end
- NodeJs for back-end
- PostgreSQL for database.

I am now adding a functionality for the user to chat with other users The conversations will be private which means one-to-one conversations.

Initially I was making a `POST` request when one user was sending a message to other and was making `GET` request continuously for fetching the chat for both users until the chat window for anyone user is open.

This idea was not good enough so I decided to use WebSockets. Also, I thought RabbitMQ would also be helpful for this scenario.

How can I use STOMP WebSocket with RabbitMQ to implement this scenario?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on the Internet for how to build Javascript chat applications with STOMP + WebSockets. Why not follow one of those instead of asking here?

Comment: Hi Justin, Thanks for your suggestion. Actually, I didn't find a suitable resource. I can implement this. I am looking for an idea to go ahead.

Comment: Asking, "How can I use STOMP WebSocket with RabbitMQ to implement this scenario?" is just too broad & vague. It's going to lead to discussion and opinion-based answers. This is why tutorials exist to answer this question. I recommend you start implementing a solution and then ask clear, specific questions when you hit problems along the way.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. You are right actually.